# can anyone explain to me why the following two arrow functions are equivalent?

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, destructuring

I am pretty new to javascript. saw this on MDN regarding arrow functions.

Can anyone explain to me how does the 2nd one work? I understand the first one. 
Not quite sure why we put length in an object, and then return the length???

Case 1 (which i understand from how it transformed from ES5):

```
materials.map((material) => {
return material.length;
}); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

Case 2 (not getting what `{length}` is doing here and also why do we return `length`:

```
materials.map(({length}) => length); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

Thank you so much!

**Update:**

So reading from the answer from Jeff B. It appears that the 2nd one is doing the following with destructuring:

`materials.map(({length}) => length)`

in which `{length}` will set a variable `var length` to equal to `materials.length`; and that's why we can simply return `length`. That makes sense. Thanks Jeff

Comment: Glad to help! If my answer is enough to consider your problem solved, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkbox to the left of it. That way future users can find it, and other potential answerers know you've got a solution. Good luck in your ES6 exploration!

Comment: Thanks Jeff. You are a great guy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get at the `length` property without saving the whole object. Specifically, this is a case of ["object destructuring"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

For instance:

```
let yourObject = {foo: 1, bar: 2}
let {bar} = yourObject;
// bar now equals 2
```

With this in mind, you can see how `({length}) => length` sets the name `length` to the `length` property of the first parameter *and then immediately returns it*—making the two expressions equivalent.